# Can an artificial Dungeon biome be created?

Tags: terraria

Can I build a Dungeon biome in a location of my choosing using blocks harvested from the naturally-occurring Dungeon?

Similarly, can I create an artificial Lizahrd Temple Biome?

If so, what are the requirements for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, artificial Dungeon Biomes cannot be created.**

The requirements to make a dungeon are set [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Artificial_biomes), specifically:

- Must be below the surface level of the world
- Must consist of 250 dungeon brick
- All 250 of said dungeon brick must be place behind *naturally occurring* dungeon walls.

Player-placed dungeon walls, do not meet the requirement. Therefore, the existing dungeon is the only place in the world where a dungeon biome can exist.

Comment: Could I do it with a map editor?

Comment: @mouseas - Sure.  But then it would not be artificial now would it?

Answer (score -1):

It is, theoretically possible to re-create certain biomes in terraria, but without any sort of modding instrument, it is nearly impossible, unless you want to spend LITERALLY hundreds of digging and then replacing blocks.

The mechanic is, which i'm sure you're aware of, that if enough of a certain type of blocks are in an area, certain mobs will spawn and it will be considered a 'biome'. a good example of this is when a meteor crashes onto the map, replacing several hundered blocks in a circle around the point of impact with meteorite ore. Once a certain amount of meteorite blocks are onscreen, the mob 'Meteor Head' will spawn rapidly. It is possible to re-create this effect by placing a certain amount of ore in another location, spawning the Meteor Heads and allowing for good farming action.

The same effect is present for dungeons. However, the amount of blocks needed to re-create the biome is MUCH higher. And you need both the blocks and the wall sections for them it work. I personally made a castle out of the blocks from my dungeon, both the walls and the backgrounds, and i never had any mobs spawn in my base.

Regardless, any artificially created dungeon biome would not have any of the naturally occuring items, like chests, bookshelves and the like.

So, long story short, yes, it is POSSIBLE, but the work and many hours involved would probably not be worth your time. Hope this helps.

Comment: Except its not possible with dungeons.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is possible to make both but really really hard. A whole bunch of brick and wall and will probably take you hours so if you're gonna do have someone help you so it's not as long

Comment: Wrong. Dungeon and Jungle Temple biomes that spawn their specific enemies cannot be artificially created. Any artificially-made Dungeon will only spawn forest/cave biome enemies (depending on depth), and an articial Jungle Temple biome is similar.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is possible it just needs a crap ton of dungeon bricks and needs to be underground . You can use the DCU (drill containment unit ) to get all of the bricks and clear out an area .

Comment: Does this make it a dungeon biome though?