# Can a working artificial Lihzarhd Temple biome be created?

Tags: terraria

This question arises out of another, similar question: [Can an artificial Dungeon biome be created?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169296/can-an-artificial-dungeon-biome-be-created)

Can I take Lihzarhd Blocks and walls to another location and build a temple biome, and have Lihzarhds + flying serpents spawn?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this wiki page](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Lihzahrd_Brick_Wall), it is possible.

> Lihzahrd Brick Walls can be used to make an artificial jungle temple biome (Just change in music), but for Lihzahrds and Flying Snakes to spawn, Lihzahrd Bricks must be present as well.